# Touch event doesn't contain getAxisValue method

Tags: android, touch, nosuchmethoderror

My application has a minimum API level set to 10 and the main activity extends SherlockActivity which is basically a regular activity. I wanted to use the touch event, so I used this code:

```
@Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    try
    {
      float x1 = event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_X);
```

However, an exception was thrown:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.MotionEvent.getAxisValue
```

According to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html), getAxisValue was added at API level 1. Why can't I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAxisValue (int axis)` is added in api level 12.

Comment: My bad, really. I just checked the main class API level.